# How can I convert a velocity expression to JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, velocity

I have a page which I'm converting from Velocity to JSP.  I have some complex expressions which I can't figure out how to convert to JSTL el language.

```
#set ($col = 0)

#foreach ($hour in $form.bean.grid.hours)
  $hour.cells.get($col).hourOfDay
  #set ($col = $col + 1)
#end
```

Hour is an object which contains a cell which contains a list. I need to get each element through a numeric index.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you're displaying hours of day. Using JSTL,

```
<c:forEach items="${form.bean.grid.hours}" var="hour" varStatus="index">
   ${hour.cells[index.count - 1].hourOfDay}
</c:forEach>
```

The `count` in index.count starts counting from 1 to N (so negate it by 1).

Comment: Rather use `LoopTagStatus#getIndex()`, i.e. `index.index` in the given example. It's 0-based, no need to substract it with 1. Javadoc here: http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html

Comment: To avoid confusion, I would declare `varStatus` as `loop`. I.e. `<c:forEach ... varStatus="loop">${foo[loop.index]}</c:forEach>`. Much more self-explaining.

Comment: Thanks BalusC, obviously you got time in your hands giving advice to every java problems on SO. :-D

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
<c:set var="col" value="0"/>

<c:forEach items="${form.bean.grid.hours}" var="hour">
   ${hour.cells[col].hourOfDay}
   <c:set var="col" value="${col + 1}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

This will only work if `hour.cells` is a `Map`, so that the `cells.get($col)` expression in the original is calling `get()` on that `Map`. If it's an arbitrary method call, then it won't work, since JSP EL can only handle bean properties or collections.

As @EliteGentleman points out, you can use the `varStatus` on the `forEach` loop to remove the need for a separate loop counter, which you should do. My fragment was a more literal translation.

Comment: Ahh, the light-bulb went ON. Thanks.  I see now how EL works differently than velocity.